# Can't mount Iphone 5s with iOS10

Tags: mount, iphone

After updating to iOS10 I can't mount my Iphone, I see the phone in the file-explorer and can share the network but can't access the files.
Having Ubuntu 14.04 LTS also try with LinuxMint 17,3 with JDK 8 same result. But in win 10 no problem. Is it something with the SSL certificate?
Before the updating I had no problem to access the phone.

Sorry for my explanation I connect the phone with usb cabel, enter the pin cod. But I can't see the files on the phone just received a error can't monunt. So what is wrong and how to fix it? / Thank you in advance

Comment: No, the issue probably not caused by X.509 ("SSL") certificates. Now what is your actual question?

Comment: Do you have a password or key code? Have you unlocked the phone at the lock screen? Explain any extra troubleshooting you have tried.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Sorry for my explanation I connect the phone with usb cabel, enter the pin cod. Then it appears in the filemanager But I can't see the files on the phone just received a error can't monunt. So what is wrong and how to fix it? / Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Unless you use (not yet officially released) libimobiledevice 1.2.1, there's no way to do anything with iOS 10 devices. You may get different errors coming from the strenghtened SSL/TLS requirements in iOS 10, like:

```
$ sudo ifuse /media/iphone
GnuTLS error: Error in the pull function.
Failed to connect to lockdownd service on the device.
Try again. If it still fails try rebooting your device.
```

Or:

```
$ ideviceinfo
GnuTLS error: Error in the pull function.
ERROR: Could not connect to lockdownd, error code -5
```

And so on. [Github issue to follow](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/issues/380).

Comment: This is very accurate. I was able to get my wife's 6s Plus accessible on my Lubuntu 16.04 by building the library myself.  Fairly straightforward: clone the repo, run `autogen.sh` and then `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib /usr/bin/ifuse /path/to/your/intended/mountpoint`. I also followed [this link](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/linux-iphone-6.html) to get some background on the process.

Answer (score 1):

Like @zgoda said, there is no way of achieving that unless you use the unofficial releases of libiimobiledevie. However, for the time being, you can use a trick that involves a virtual machine. I have written a walk-through tutorial describing how to [connect iOS 10+ devices to Linux hosts using a VirtualBox](https://www.khalidalnajjar.com/connect-ios-10-linux/). I hope this is helpful.

Here is a summary of how this can be done, thanks @Zanna for your comment:

1) Install VirtualBox and VirtualBox Extension Pack

2) Install a Windows virtual machine, a free one can be obtained from Microsoft's website (couldn't link it as I need 10+ reputation). The virtual machine will expire in 90 days, so you should take a snapshot of the virtual machine once you are done configuring it.

3) Install Guest Additions on Windows VM.

4) Run the below command in Ubuntu's terminal, to add your user to VirtualBox's group.

```
sudo adduser $USER vboxusers
```

5) Enable USB and USB 2.0 (EHCI) controllers from the Virtual Machine's USB settings.

6) Done! Boot the VM and connect your iOS device, it should work. You can install iTunes on Windows. Also, create a shared folder between the VM and host. Finally, don't forget to take a snapshot of the VM.