# Can't mount iphone 5 with iOS10 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mount, iphone

I was able to access pictures and music prior to iOS10 on Ubuntu 14.04.  Then iOS10 came along and I hit the 'trust issue' where it asks to trust the computer and nothing happens.  I read that Ubuntu 16.04 had an upgraded version of libimobiledevice, so I upgraded to 16.04.  Now I plugin my iPhone and it at least recognizes the device has photos (doesn't recognize music) and asks what to do, I select to import with gThumb or Shotwell, but neither actually work, they can't seem to find the photos.

I've read this question [Can't mount iphone 5s with iOS10 on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/830803/cant-mount-iphone-5s-with-ios10) and it seems I need an even newer version of libimobiledevice (1.2.1).  I have now built this locally (after having to build libplist and libusbmuxd), however it hasn't made any difference, I still have the exact same behaviour.

Do I need to uninstall the existing libimobiledevice package?

libimobiledevice6/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1.2.0+dfsg-3~ubuntu0.2 i386 [installed,automatic]

ie, how do I ensure it will use my locally built library when I plug the phone in?